# Algorithm get a new list containing no duplicated item by adding any 2 elements in a big array

Tags: algorithm

I can only think of this naive algorithm. Any better way? C/C++, Ruby ,Haskell is OK.

```
arry = [1,5,.....4569895] //1000000 elements ,sorted , no duplicated
newArray = Hash.new
for (i = 0 ; i < arry.length ;i++ )
{
       for (j = 0 ; j < arry.length ;j ++ )
       {
                elem = arry[i] + arry[j]
                if (! newArray.key?(elem))
                {
                    newArray [elem] = arry[i] + arry[j]
                }

       }

}
```

EDIT : sorry. I have discrete value in the array , instead of [1..1000000]

Comment: note that you can optimize the inner `for`: `for (j = i; ...)`

Comment: you should explain better **what you have** and **what you want**

Comment: In my interpretation: [1,3,5,7] -> [1+3, 1+5, 1+7=3+5, 3+7, 5+7] = [4,6,8,10,12]

Comment: Acutally this is an quite interesting problem. Depending on the values of the array you could get less than the worst case 10^12 elements in the new array, for the given example it could be around 9*10^6 elements. Maybe the other way around is an option, first generation all numbers up to the maximum and then finding value paris which sum is the searched value. This has O(N^2*log N) in the worst case using a binary search, but could potentially be (N*log N).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be more efficient to separate the algorithm into two distinct steps. (Warning: pseudocode ahead)

First create n-1 lists by adding the rest of the elements to the ith element. This can be done in parallel for each list. Note that the resulting lists will be sorted.

```
newArray = array(array.length);
for (i = 0 ; i < array.length ;i++ ) {
  newArray[i] = array(array.length - i - 1);
  for (j = 0; j < array.length - i; j++) {
    newArray[i][j] = array[i] + array[j + i];
  }
}
```

Second use [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) in to merge the resulted lists. You can do this in parallel, e.g. merge newArray[0] - newArray[i], newArray[2] - newArray[1-i], ... and then again until you only have one list.

Answer (score 0):

If the condition says that you should be able to add **any** item in the range, then the only way i can think of is to check if the sum is not yet in the result list. Since for any number x, there are x different additions that lead to x. (Or x/2 if you think that 1 + 2 and 2 + 1 is the same addition).

Answer (score 0):

There is one obvious optimization: make the second loop start at the indice i, that way you will avoid having x+y and y+x.

Then if you don't want to use a set, you could use the fact that the items are sorted, so you could build N lists, and merge them while removing the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the best worst-case time complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>). For input {2<sup>0</sup>, 2<sup>1</sup>, 2<sup>2</sup>, ...}, you won't get any duplicate adding these numbers. Assuming hash insertions are O(1), you already have the best algorithm...

Comment: Just going through the list adding the numbers is O(n2) already, isn't it ?